# Ember-CLI: Conditional asset import

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Im using Ember-CLI to build an application.
Now i want to import script files with the asset pipeline, but only if a condition is true.

i.e.:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script src="jquery1x.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

How could i do this wih the Asset pipeline?
If this is not possible trough the Asset pipeline: what is the best practice to do it another way?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript to check for your conditions, you can do it in your Brocfile:

```
// Brocfile.js
var app = new EmberApp();

if (lteIE9) {
  app.import('jquery1x.min.js');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I think i still have to learn a lot about JS. Didnt even realize that the if statement is js.. But how couldnt it be? Shame on me. Do you have some ressources for me about that topic?

Comment: The `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` in your HTML code is not JS, I was saying if you are able to find out within your JS if the browser is less than IE9 (perhaps using a library, I'm not sure), you could do the conditional import in your brocfile.

Comment: I just remembered that the brocfile compiles my assets during development to a vendor.css and vendor.js, so it is impossible to do this at all. But thanks for your answer!